# How can I take the row product of columns in a dataframe with a common string

Tags: r

I have N columns that start with the String "Factor". I want to create an additional column in the dataframe that finds the row product of those columns.

Example data (My actual data set N = 50):

```
df <- data.frame(Company = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                Factor1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                Factor2 = c(5,4,3,2,1),
                FactorN = c(2,4,6,8,10))
```

Expected result

```
 df2 <- data.frame(Company = c("A","B","C","D","E"),
                    Factor1 = c(1,2,3,4,5),
                    Factor2 = c(5,4,3,2,1),
                    FactorN = c(2,4,6,8,10),
Factor_Product = c(10,32,54,64,50))
```

I've tried rowProds from the matrixStats package, but that requires a matrix format.

Comment: did you try adding `as.matrix(df)` to your `rowProds` call, rather than just using the `df` as it is?

Comment: There are lots of dupes for this.  See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48879643/rowwise-matrix-multiplication-in-r) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48924407/continually-multiply-many-columns-to-form-a-new-variable) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1457821/adding-multiple-columns-transforming-with-multiple-variables/1458691#1458691) and many others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Then convert it into matrix format and select columns which start with `"Factor"`

```
matrixStats::rowProds(as.matrix(df[grep("^Factor", names(df))]))
#[1] 10 32 54 64 50
```

---

You can also use `apply` row-wise

```
apply(df[grep("Factor", names(df))], 1, prod)
```

Comment: Thanks! Exactly what I needed.